# C# Dropdown items 0 - 100 without adding each item?

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry if this is a dumb question ... I'm just trying to learn the best way to do it.  Basically I want to have a dropdown list with values blank and then 0 - 100.

Whats is the best way to do this without manually entering each one.  I imagine it is through some form of a list bound to the dropdown.

Thankyou in advance for the help.

Comment: Please tell us what kind of application you are developing. Is it WinForms? WebForms? MVC? Silverlight? Etc...

Comment: That sounds like really terrible usability. Nielsen Norman has produced a lot of research showing it's often better to provide free-form text with validation than a very long choice list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
ddl.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select (e => new ListItem(e.ToString())).ToArray());
```

Comment: How does this handle the blank at the beginning?

Comment: @Ben It doesn't, but I dont think that was the problem in the question.

Comment: Not to be overly pedantic, but question reads: "Basically I want to have a dropdown list with values blank and then 0 - 100".

Comment: This adds 0-100 to the existing items in the list, if he starts off with a blank item, it'll be fine.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use a `for` loop.

```
myControl.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Empty, -1));
for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
{
    var newOption = new ListItem("Item #" + (j + 1).ToString(), j.ToString());
    myControl.Items.Add(newOption);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wanted a dropdown with the values `"",0,1,2,3..` so it should probably be `myControl.Items.Add(j.ToString())` and you missed the empty string.

Comment: Sure... but the more important facet is that he can just use a for loop for the repetitive addition of the 0-99 elements.

Comment: Agreed but it would be a better answer if you included a solution that actually solved the problem the OP asked. Also including a more general solution is good too.

Comment: Updated with more concrete solution then.

Answer (score 3):

If you bound the list (array, collection, etc...) as datasource into the dropdown (winforms? webforms?) there always will created items. If you don't want add each item manualy, you can do it with code:

```
// this code is for winforms
dropDown.Items.Clear();
dropDown.Items.Add( string.Empty );
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++ ) {
    dropDown.Items.Add( i.ToString() );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For instance in asp.net MVC:

Controller:

```
ViewData["list"] = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(0, 101)
                .Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Text = p.ToString(), Value = p.ToString() }));
```

View:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("numbers", ViewData["list"] as SelectList, "Select a number") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is webforms:
I imagine you want something like this in your page_load event.

```
if(Page.IsNotPostBack)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("",""));
    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ddl.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
ddl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
combo.Items.Add("")
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  combo.Items.Add(i)
```

Also, consider using a [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/729xt55s.aspx) control with a maximum value of 100. This won't give you the blank choice, but is an arguably nicer usability choice.

Answer (score 0):

Create a utility to generate your values:

```
public class Utils
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetSequenceEntries(long maxValue)
    {
        yield return string.Empty;

        for(int i=1; i<=maxValue; i++)
        {
            yield return i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then for a WinForms application bind it similar to this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = Utilities.Utils.GetSequenceEntries(100).ToList<string>();
}
```

Or for ASP.NET bind it like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddl1.DataSource = Utilities.Utils.GetSequenceEntries(100);
    ddl1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: There already is a `Range` function in C#.
`ddl.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select (e => new ListItem(e.ToString())).ToArray());`

Comment: @Magnus maybe you should put that as an answer?

Comment: @Magnus Please Post that as a answer and I will mark it as the answer I think it is the most elegant solution !  Thankyou everyone for all the input.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna I'll do that :-)

Comment: In the case of this specific dropdown list, directly adding the items might be OK, but in general a data source bound to the dropdown provides more flexibility.  I also like the enumerable range suggestion that Magnus offered.  Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

**vb:**

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 100
                ddlperiod.Items.Add(i)
            Next
```